# Why are important, high-ranking (highly frequent) words that are not stop words missing in my word cloud?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, word-cloud

[image]I uploaded a list of highly frequent words which includes stop words and I used the STOPWORDS list to remove stop words. When I print my word cloud, it's not displaying several non-stopwords that are high ranking.

For example, "data" and "learning" appear more frequently than "distribution", "algorithm" and such. Other words like "training", "regression" are also missing despite ranking high in frequency. (No, none of these words exist in the STOPWORDS list.) How can I get words like "data", "learning", "training" to appear according to their frequency?
(I've attached a screenshot of the words/frequencies.)

Here's the code:

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
text = open("test.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8").read()

wc = WordCloud(background_color="white", stopwords=STOPWORDS, height=400, width=600)
wc.generate(text)
wc.to_file("my_first_word_cloud.png")
```

[image]

Comment: what does `test.txt` contain?

Answer (score 2):

I've created a solution that utilises the WordCloud `generate_from_frequencies()` function as I believe this gives you more control over how you want to preprocess the words/frequencies being fed into the WordCloud object and can help with debugging your specific situation.

Using the word/frequency values shown in the image you provided, I created a `test.txt` file with the first line as a header (i.e. `Word,Frequency`) and lines thereafter containing comma separated word-frequency pairs (see below). I presume you have a similar file.

```
Word,Frequency
the,38732
and,11580
for,7682
...
than,729
follows,723
parameter,718
```

### Solution

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS

# Generally it is best practice to use the built-in Python 
# context manager to handle files and let it manage closing/clean-up
with open("test.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    text = file.read()

# Convert file to dict using built-in python functions 
# and list comprehension, filtering entries that are stop words
# Note: the "[1:]" skips over the header "Word,Frequency" in the
# test.txt file, remove it if there is no header in your file
textDict = {key: int(val) for key, val in [line.split(',') \
    for line in text.split('\n')[1:]] if key not in STOPWORDS}

# If you want to normalise frequency values
import numpy as np
valsArr = np.array([val for val in textDict.values()])
# Calc L1 (Manhattan Distance) & L2 (Euclidean) norms
norm1 = np.abs(valsArr).sum(axis=0)
norm2 = np.sqrt((valsArr**2).sum(axis=0))
# Note: L2 norm squares components which means that outliers can skew results
# Thus, if outliers present, use L1, else use L2
# Normalise frequency values
textDictNorm = {key:textDict[key]/norm2 for key in textDict.keys()}

# For debugging: uncomment to display dicts containing word:frequency pairs
# print(textDict)
# print(textDictNorm)

# Create word cloud object
wc = WordCloud(background_color="white", height=400, width=600)
# Generate word cloud from normalised word:frequency dict
wc.generate_from_frequencies(textDictNorm)
# Export word cloud to file
wc.to_file("my_first_word_cloud.png")
```

### Output

[image: Word Cloud generated using test.txt file]

Answer (score 1):

If you want frequencies maybe try:

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
text = open("test.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8").read()

wc = WordCloud(background_color="white", stopwords=STOPWORDS, height=400, width=600)
wc.generate_from_frequencies(text)
wc.to_file("my_first_word_cloud.png")
```

Have a look at the `wc` documentation [here](https://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/generated/wordcloud.WordCloud.html)

Comment: I believe you're on the right track with using the `generate_from_frequencies()` function, however, it requires a dictionary as input and `read()` reads some quantity of data and returns it as a string (in text mode) or bytes object (in binary mode), so this code wouldn't work. Additionally, `generate_from_frequencies()` does not use the stoplist as the intent is to do the processing yourself when using this function (see [this](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/issues/132) "issue" on the `word_cloud` repo).